# Inject data from MongoDB into chart.js

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I'm building a little app and I need to inject data from MongoDB which looks like this :
[image]

And there is my chart which looks like this :

```
labels : ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'],
    datasets: [ {
      data: [ 170.3, 108.75, 35.3, 37.98 ]
    } ]
```

What I would like is :

- **In labels : It needs to contain all the "titre" data ( See the picture ) , if one "titre" is used more than once, it needs to display only one**
- **In data, it needs to add every items from the "montant" ordered by category**

I'm sure nobody will understand  Sorry

### Example : They are 3 documents with the "titre" groceries.
The "montant" are 4, 7 , 12 So the chart needs to look like this :

```
labels : ['Groceries', 'label2', 'label3'],
    datasets: [ {
      data: [ 23, ..., ... ]
    } ]
```

How can I achieve this in the component.ts ?

Thank you everyone !

Comment: Can you already get the data in your component? Where are you at this point and what do you need help with?

Comment: To get such data from the collection, you need to perform an Aggregation Query. The pipeline will have a `$group` stage to accumulate values for `labels` and `data` - `$push` and `$addToSet` accumulators are useful in this case.

Comment: Well I guess I need to get back to learning...